# Firebreath plugin installation available for all users

Tags: wix, firebreath

i have a problem with the installation of a Firebreath plugin on Windows XP machine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 setup project to place generated plugin dll in program folder to get the plugin work but when i run the installer the plugin is usable only by the user who install the plugin and if i log in the machine with another user with limited privileges Firefox cannot see the plugin.

1. What i'm doing wrong with this process?
2. Should i use Wix installer instead of Visual studio 2008 setup project to get the plugin work for all users in the machine ?
3. What is the correct "Firebreath" way to install a plugin and to make it visible to all users in the machine?

Thank for your time!

Francesco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Nothing. This is as designed; FireBreath installs per-user by default, always has. This is a feature, since it means you don't have to have administrator privileges to install.

2) Not by default, no.

3) Uncomment the following line in your PluginConfig.cmake file and rerun the prep script:

```
# If you want to register per-machine on Windows, uncomment this line
set (FB_ATLREG_MACHINEWIDE 1)
```